# Ruby: Select element from multidimensional array which matches a given block

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am building a Chess program in Ruby and my Square objects are in a multi-dimensional array.

#### Example code for Square class:

```
class Square
  attr_accessor :piece_on_square, :x, :y, :coordinates
  def initialize(piece_on_square=nil, x=nil, y=nil, coordinates=nil)
    @piece_on_square = piece_on_square
    @x = x
    @y = y
    @coordinates = coordinates
  end
end
```

#### Code within my Board class:

```
@square_array = Array.new(8){Array.new(8){Square.new}}
```

The problem comes when I try to select a Square object in the `@square_array` which matches a condition (such as a Square with `coordinates` of `"a4"`). I've tried using nested `#each_with_index` calls with `#select` but that isn't working. I've only been able to select the array itself, not the object in the array. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Create some example with values in square and explain what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: FYI: In Ruby, you don't have to pre-create the array the way you do it in Java or C++.  This code will perfectly fine - `arr = [];arr[10] = "Hi";p arr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see many people building nested arrays for doing this kind of thing, encountering various problems that stem from using nested arrays. The obvious solution is: **get rid of nested arrays, and use a flat array**.

If I were to do such programming, I would use a flat array, and do row/column operations using the array index and modulo operations (`Fixnum#%` for columns, `Fixnum#/` for rows).

But in your case, you seem to be saving the column and row numbers, and even the coordinate name, for each square, so it is easier for you to use **a flat hash with either the row-column combination or the coordinate name as the key**.

Comment: Originally I actually had a flat array but changed it to a 2d array because I thought it is more OO (a board is an 8x8 grid, not 64 spaces) and would be easier when I wanted to display the board. However, you're right, because I'm keeping track of x and y values in addition to the coordinate name, it may be easier in the long run to move it back to a flat array

Comment: @scobo Do you think a row in a chess board has any reality/significance to be modeled as an object, (while leaving aside the columns)? I don't think so.